# Neo4j Traversal Framework Expander and Ordering

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, graph-traversal

I am trying to understand Neo4J java traversal API but after a thorough reading I am stuck on certain points.

What I seem to know:

Difference between `PathExpander` and `BranchOrderingPolicy`. As per my understanding, the former tells what relationships are eligible to be explored from a particular position and the latter specifies the ordering in which they should be evaluated.

I would like to know the following things:

1. Whether or to what extent this understanding is correct or if it can be altered to give the correct understanding.
2. If correct, how is `PathExpander` different from `Evaluator`.
3. How does `PathExpander` and `BranchOrderingPolicy` work. What I intend to ask is, is `PathExpander` consulted everytime a relationship is added to the traversal and what does it do with the iterable of relationships returned. Similarly with branch ordering.
4. During traversal how and when do the components `Expander`, `BranchOrdering`, `Evaluator`, `Uniqueness` come into picture. Basically I wish to know the template algorithm where one would say like first expander is asked for a collection of relationships to expand and then ordering policy is consulted to select one of the eligibles....
5. If correct, does the ordering policy specified by `BranchOrderingPolicy` apply on the eligible relationships only(after expander has done). Perhaps it must be.

Please include anything else that might be helpful in understanding the API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll try to describe these parts to the best of my ability.

1. As to the difference between `PathExpander` and `BranchOrderingPolicy`: a `PathExpander` is invoked for each traversal branch the first time the traversal continues from that branch. (A traversal branch is a node including the path leading up to that node, note that there may be many paths, i.e. many branches to the same node, mostly depending on uniqueness). The result of invoking the `PathExpander` is an `Iterator<Relationship>` which will lazily provide new relationships off of that traversal branch when needed. That brings us to `BranchOrderingPolicy` which looks at all alive traversal branches. By "alive" I mean a branch that has one or more relationships on it such that more branches can be created from it. Given all alive branches it picks one of them, following its next relationship (retreived from the relationship iterator on that branch, potentially if it's the first call initializes that iterator using the `PathExpander` (as described above).
2. Difference between `PathExpander` and `Evaluator`: that split is very much a matter of convenience and separation of concerns. `PathExpander` grows the number of branches and `Evaluator` filters, i.e. reduces the number of branches. An expander creates new branches that are evaluated by the `Evaluator`. With that said you can write a `PathExpander` that does both those things and it could be more efficient doing so. But the convenience of having them separated, where there can be multiple `Evaluator`s is quite useful.
3. See above (1)
4. Some of this is described in (1), but a broader picture would be that the `BranchOrderingPolicy` is the driver in the traversal - out of every alive branch it picks one and follows it one relationship out to a new branch. Only branches that comply with the selected uniqueness will be created. The relationships for a branch are retreived on the first time this happens for every branch, in the form of a lazy relationship iterator using the `PathExpander`. New branches get evaluated the first time they are selected where one result of the evaluation is whether or not this branch is a dead end and the other is whether or not to include it in the result out to the user.
5. I think the above explains that

Is this sufficient information?

Comment: thanks @Mattias... I think this was good enough for me to introspect my own understandings.